# Changing Hover color of Hyperlink

Tags: win-universal-app

Currently struggeling understanding how to style the `Windows.UI.Xaml.Documents.Hyperlink` textelement proper ...
The problem is simple: Changing the "normal" foreground color works fine but as soon as the hyperlink gets hovered it changes its color (which is simple to explain)

The question i struggle with is: how to change the foreground of other visual states of a hyperlink textelement (black on black looks very bad ... :) )?

```
Hyperlink lnk = new Hyperlink();
lnk.Inlines.Add(new Run { Text = linkText });
lnk.Foreground = Application.Current.Resources["pr0_orange"] as SolidColorBrush;
```

greetings
X39

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to **Hyperlink and theme/style behavior** from [HyperLink class article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.documents.hyperlink.aspx),

> Hyperlink doesn't inherit from Control, so it doesn't have a Style property or a Template. You can edit the properties that are inherited from TextElement, such as Foreground or FontFamily, to change the appearance of a Hyperlink, but you can't use a common style or template to apply changes. Instead of using a template, consider using common resources for values of Hyperlink properties to provide consistency. Some properties of Hyperlink use defaults from a {ThemeResource} markup extension value provided by the system. This enables the Hyperlink appearance to switch in appropriate ways when the user changes the system theme at run-time.

You cannot change the hover foreground color in a style or template. The only way is to change the `SystemControlHyperlinkBaseMediumBrush` property value of  system ThemeResource. But I strongly recommend you not to do this because it will change all the relative styles.

You can use [HyperlinkButton](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299132.aspx), which you can change the hover color by simply set the `PointerOver` VisualState.
If HyperlinkButton cannot meet your requirements well, recommend you to custom a control.

Comment: sadly it is impossible for me to use hyperlinkButton unless it would be possible to fiddle it into a RichTextBlock which also contains text somehow ...

hoped i missed something obvious in the documentation or whatever ... but looks like they just forgot about it

Comment: @X39 In that case, custom a control is the best way for you.